# The difference between interpolating polynomials

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

I've been trying to understand Newton Interpolation and I've found a proof that I am able to wrap my head around: [http://www.math.umd.edu/~mariakc/teaching-2/interpolation.pdf](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Emariakc/teaching-2/interpolation.pdf) , page 3.
But there's one thing stated which I am not sure about, namely that

*Suppose the polynomials
$P[x_0, . . . , x_{n−1}](x)$ and $P[x_1, . . . , x_n](x)$ of the form of Eq. (2) $$ P_n(x) = f[x_0] + f[x_0, x_1](x − x_0) + f[x_0, x_1, x_2](x − x_0)(x − x_1) + . . . + f[x_0, x_1, . . . , x_n](x − x_0)(x − x_1). . .(x − x_{n−1}). $$ interpolate $f$ at the points
$x_0, . . . , x_{n−1}$ and $x_1, . . . , x_n$ respectively. They differ by a polynomial of degree $n − 1$ **that
has zeros at $x_1, ..., x_{n−1}$.***

I understand that there must be $n-1$ zeros / roots.
I have written out the difference
$$P[x_1, . . . , x_n](x)-P[x_0, . . . , x_{n−1}](x) = $$ $$f[x_1]-f[x_0]+f[x_1,x_2](x-x_1)-f[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)...+...-...+f[x_1, ..., x_{n-1}(x-x_1)...(x-x_{n-1})-f[x_0, ..., x_{n-2}(x-x_0)...(x-x_{n-2})$$

and verified for up to some n. But I would like a general proof, since it's my only missing piece to understand the Newton Interpolation proof in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the first interpolant is $p$ and the second interpolant is $q$, now $p$ and $q$ have at most degree $n-1$ by definition, so $p-q$ does as well. Additionally, $p$ and $q$ agree at $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1}$ by hypothesis, so $p-q$ has zeros there. Therefore, without needing to know anything about $f$, you know what $p-q$ is, except for a multiplicative constant, because of the fundamental theorem of algebra. That's really all this step is for.

What's less obvious is why you care about $p-q$ at all. And honestly, this way of setting things up obfuscates that a little bit, I think.

The idea behind this entire setup is, if you have an interpolant $p$ on $x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}$ and an interpolant $q$ on $x_1,\dots,x_n$, you can "glue them together" by looking at $r(x)=p(x)+c(x)(q(x)-p(x))$, provided that $c(x_0)=0$ (so that $r(x_0)=p(x_0)$) and $c(x_n)=1$ (so that $r(x_n)=q(x_n)$). It doesn't matter what $c$ does at the other nodes because $r(x)=p(x)$ at the other nodes automatically. So now you just choose $c(x)=\frac{x-x_0}{x_n-x_0}$ and you're set to go.

Comment: Superficially, to me it looks like the interpolants disagree on both $x_1$ and $x_{n-1}$? With $x_1$ lying outside of the scope of q, and $x_{n-1}$ lying outside the scope of p?

Comment: @Sondr No, they agree on those points too (because they agree with $f$ itself at all those points). Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: $Q[x_1, x_2, ... , x_n](x)$ is equal to $f$ on ${x_1, x_2, ..., x_n}$, while $Q(x_0)$ would be extrapolation and inaccurate. And $P[x_0, x_1, ... , x_{n-1}](x)$ is equal to $f$ on ${x_0, x_1, ..., x_{n-1}}$, while $P(x_n)$ would be extrapolating. I think that is one of the starting assumptions.

Comment: @Sondr Yes, so what you do is build a new polynomial that is equal to $P$ on $x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}$ and equal to $Q$ at $x_n$. Then you're never extrapolating. Both polynomials interpolate at $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$, here.

Comment: Hmm, well at least I get that the new polynomial $r(x)=p(x)+c(x)(q(x)−p(x))$ covers all those values. I don't know what I don't see here. I guess that $q(x_n)−p(x_n) = 0$ is just an assumption.

Comment: @Sondr No, at $x_n$ they usually do *not* agree. But that wasn't used anywhere. Where they are guaranteed to agree is just $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Sondr One thing that might be confusing you: as an example of it, the *coefficient* of $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$ involves $x_2$. So although the last term of $p$ only involves the product of $x-x_j$ up to $j=n-2$, the coefficient involves $x_{n-1}$ also. This is related to the fact that a polynomial of degree $d$ allows for interpolation at $d+1$ points.

Comment: Yes, looking at it again I think this has got to do with why I didn't understand it. Thanks